# Route available in response in Compojure API

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

I need the uninterpolated path (e.g., /resources/:resourceId) available in the response to log the duration with the path. What is the appropriate way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the uninterpolated path as an argument to your response function. The simplest example would be:

```
(GET "/resources/:resourceId" [resourceId]
  (str "resourceId: " resourceId ", Path: /resources/:resourceId"))
```

where the response contains both the extracted `resourceId` parameter and the original route path.